# Sample of 3 from 5: Permutation or Combination?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations, combinations

I answered this question correctly using combinations rather than permutations. Is my solution valid, or am I misreading the question?

"A sample of size 3 is drawn at random and without replacement from the population $\{1, 2, 3, 4, 5\}$. What is the probability that the range of the sample is equal to 3?"

My logic: Because we are interested in the events where the range is three, I concluded that the cardinality of the sample N from the population $P$ is  #$(N) = 4$ because $N = \{(1, 2, 4), (1, 3, 4), (2, 3, 5), (2, 4, 5)\}$.

So then the $P($range$ = 3) =\dfrac{4}{5 \choose 3} = \dfrac{4}{10}$.

Solution: There are six possible orderings for both $(1,2,4)$ and $(1,3,4)$, which is also true for both $(2,3,5)$ and $(2,4,5)$. So there are 24 ways to select the three good sets and $(5)(4)(3)= 60$ ways to select three from $P$. So $\dfrac{24}{60} = \dfrac{4}{10}$

Does the phrase "without replacement" imply one at a time? Or is there something in the phrasing of this question that should signal to me to use permutations rather than combinations? I was under the impression that the order they are chosen doesn't matter because the range relies on the two numbers being chosen in such a way that they are the max and minimum and the difference is 3.

Comment: "Without replacement" means that a sampled object is withdrawn from the population, so it can't be sampled a second time.  That is, there are no duplicates.  So, order doesn't matter.  I think your answer is correct.  Why do you have any doubts?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I have doubts because the solution is different than how I got the answer, and it's possible to get the right answer with the wrong logic.  I suppose permutations and combinations are logically equivalent as 5choose3 * 6 = 60?

Comment: The order in which the items re drawn doesn't affect the range, so your solution is correct.  Of course, one can also take order into account, and arrive at the same answer, as in the solution you quote.  I prefer your solution, for whatever that's worth.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is my solution valid, or am I misreading the question?

Your solution is valid.

> Or is there something in the phrasing of this question that should signal to me to use permutations rather than combinations? I was under the impression that the order they are chosen doesn't matter because the range relies on the two numbers being chosen in such a way that they are the max and minimum and the difference is 3.

You counted ways to obtain a combination with a range of 3 (maximum-minimum) when selecting three numbers.  [Select a minumum, select a middle, select a maximum such that maximum-minum=3 vs. select any three from the five numbers.]
$$\dfrac{{^2\mathrm C_1}{^2\mathrm C_1}{^1\mathrm C_1}}{^5\mathrm C_3}$$

They counted the way to obtain a permutation with a range of 3 (maximum-minimum) when selecting *and arranging* three numbers.

$$\dfrac{{^2\mathrm C_1}{^2\mathrm C_1}{^1\mathrm C_1}~ 3!}{^5\mathrm C_3~ 3!}$$

Well, now you see that here, as often is the case, the extra effort of counting ways to arrange is redundant because *the common factor cancels*.

---

**Remark:** Generally when *order is important (for the event)*, then the probability is a ratio of permutation to combination.    However, when *order is not important (for the event)*, then the probability may equally be either a ratio of combinations, or a ratio of permutations.  (*Assuming all atomic outcomes being counted are equally probable*)